# How can I describe the result of restricted cubic spline analysis?

Tags: r, rms

I am evaluating the association between levels of a biomarker A and outcome(occurrence of a disease).
The levels of a biomarker is a continuous variable.
To assess the association between the levels of a biomarker A and the odds of the outcome, i've used restricted cubic spline analysis with logistic regression as below in R:

```
d<-datadist(df)
options(datadist="d")

fit <- lrm(outcome~rcs(levels,4), data=df)

summary(fit)
anova(fit)
```

And the results were shown as

```
 > summary(fit)
         Effects              Response : outcome

 Factor      Low  High Diff. Effect    S.E.    Lower 0.95 Upper 0.95
 levels      72.5 73.1 0.6   -0.004536 0.13166 -0.26259   0.25352   
  Odds Ratio 72.5 73.1 0.6    0.995470      NA  0.76906   1.28850   

> anova(fit)
                Wald Statistics          Response: outcome

 Factor     Chi-Square d.f. P     
 levels     6.28       3    0.0986
  Nonlinear 2.38       2    0.3050
 TOTAL      6.28       3    0.0986
```

How can I interpret the results?

Is it right that
Restricted cubic spline analysis demonstrated a linear relationship between the levels of A and theoutcome (p-value for nonlineairty 0.3050) but the levels did not significantly associated with the outcome (OR 1.0, 95% CI 0.77-1.29).

Comment: Welcome to SO DANA. SO is primarily for coding and programming issues. As your question is primarily methods-based, it would be better to post [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). Thanks, and good luck